# SUM of 2 values from the same row

Tags: postgresql, sum

I am a newcomer to postgresql 9.3 and I find myself in trouble in a simple operation. I have to execute with a trigger the sum of the numerical values of two columns and write the result in a third column. This is my starting table:

```
CREATE TABLE pratica
(
  progressivo text NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pratica_prog_seq'::regclass),
  sal1_importo_arc numeric(10,2),
  sal1_spese numeric(10,2),
  sal1_totale numeric(10,2),
   note text,
  CONSTRAINT pratica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (progressivo)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

And this is the function and the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_sal1()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF NEW.sal1_importo_arc IS NULL
THEN
UPDATE pratica
SET sal1_totale = NEW.sal1_spese
WHERE pratica.sal1_totale IS DISTINCT FROM pratica.sal1_spese;
ELSE IF NEW.sal1_spese  IS NULL
THEN
UPDATE pratica
SET sal1_totale = NEW.sal1_importo_arc
WHERE pratica.sal1_totale IS DISTINCT FROM pratica.sal1_importo_arc;
ELSE
UPDATE pratica
SET sal1_totale = (SELECT (NEW.sal1_importo_arc + NEW.sal1_spese))
WHERE pratica.sal1_totale IS DISTINCT FROM (SELECT (pratica.sal1_importo_arc + pratica.sal1_spese));
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

CREATE TRIGGER sum_sal1
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF sal1_importo_arc
  ON pratica
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sum_sal1();
```

The columns `sal1_spese` and `sal1_importo_arc` may contain `NULL` values and therefore I have put the appropriate conditions.
The problem is that when the trigger is triggered, it updates the column `sal1_total` of the whole table with the same value of the modified line and not just the line of the change object.
What am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Please simplify your example as much as possible. It would be really nice too if you could translate your code into english and deliver some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to store a calculable value? You can do it in SELECT statement, or you can use view..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in expressions which may contain `NULL`.

There is no reason to update the table each time the value should be calculated, as you can use a trigger `BEFORE` in the simple way like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_sal1()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.sal1_totale = COALESCE(NEW.sal1_importo_arc, 0) + COALESCE(NEW.sal1_spese, 0);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER sum_sal1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON pratica
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sum_sal1();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!